# Not have permission to writable directory in plugins

Tags: openshift, redmine, redmine-plugins, openshift-cartridge

In information of redmine not have permission to writable directory in plugins, below image, thereby generating problems using the system.
[REDMINE IN OPENSHIFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqxX5.png)

how to solve this problem , since I reported the same in githuib but up to now no answer , anyone have any tips ?

Github: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-redmine-quickstart/issues/13

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem but not with `Redmine` but with `rails` itself.

I did use ,as `sudo` user, bundle install and this messed up the permissions of my folders.

If you are in `Ubuntu` you could change the privileges with `chmod 777` (not very secure) and try.

If you are in `Windows`, check the current user permissions for that folder.